# SFDX Pull not grabbing permission set

Tags: salesforcedx, permission-sets

I'm trying to pull a permission set that I created in my Scratch Org, however sfdx force:source:pull doesn't seem to be grabbing the permission set.

Is there a reason why this would be occurring?

I'm following this trailhead https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/sfdx_app_dev/units/sfdx_app_dev_create_app

[image: source:force:pull from trailhead]

And after setting the permission set and running `force:source:pull` I don't see line 8 from the image

This is the output I get after running pull, there is nothing about the newly created Geolocation permission set.

[image: output from runnign source:force:pull]

Comment: No errors or anything, the pull completes but you just don't see your updates? You may find this useful but without many details, I can't help as much :) https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/195775/salesforce-dx-error-retrieving-admin-profile?rq=1

Comment: @StasChristiansen correct no errors.

Comment: And then command sfdx force:user:permset:assign -n Geolocation has been run as well? I apologize for the seemingly silly questions :) if so, I might try to run the process from the top again.

Comment: @StasChristiansen yes. That command was run before `pull`, as per the Trailhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listening to @StasChristiansen I started the Trailhead again.

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/sfdx_app_dev/units/sfdx_app_dev_create_app

While doing this I noticed that I missed one of the steps, which may have been causing the issue, being that now it worked.

[image: steps I missed image]

Thank you Stas.